# Pandas split on regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have pandas df with a column containing comma-delimited characteristics like so:

```
Shot - Wounded/Injured, Shot - Dead (murder, accidental, suicide), Suicide - Attempt, Murder/Suicide, Attempted Murder/Suicide (one variable unsuccessful), Institution/Group/Business, Mass Murder (4+ deceased victims excluding the subject/suspect/perpetrator , one location), Mass Shooting (4+ victims injured or killed excluding the subject/suspect
```

I would like to split this column into multiple dummy-variable columns, but cannot figure out how to start this process.  I am trying to split on columns like so:

```
df['incident_characteristics'].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

This doesn't work, however, because there are commas in the middle of descriptions.  Instead, I need to split based on a regex match of a comma followed by a space and a capital letter.  Can str.split take regex?  If so, how is this done?

I think this Regex will do what I need:

```
,\s[A-Z]
```

Comment: So you want columns like "Shot - Wounded/Injured", "Shot - Dead", and so on? Is what you've shown an example of data from a single row of your "incident_characteristics" column?

Comment: Yes, sorry -- that is a single row, and the correct split is:

`[Shot - Wounded/Injured] , [Shot - Dead (murder, accidental, suicide)] , [Suicide - Attempt, Murder/Suicide]`

Comment: Use `\s*,\s*(?=[A-Z])`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, `split` supports regex. According to your requirements,

> split based on a regex match of a comma followed by a space and a capital letter

you may use

```
df['incident_characteristics'].str.split(r'\s*,\s*(?=[A-Z])', expand=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ECVDtm/1).

**Details**

- `\s*,\s*` - a comma enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(?=[A-Z])` - only if followed with an uppercase ASCII letter

However, it seems you also don't want to match the comma inside parentheses, add `(?![^()]*\))` lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)`:

```
r'\s*,\s*(?=[A-Z])(?![^()]*\))'
```

and it will prevent matching commas before capitalized words inside parentheses (that has no parentheses inside).

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ECVDtm/2).

Answer (score 3):

You can try `.str.extractall` (but I think there are better patterns than mine).

```
import pandas as pd

txt = 'Shot - Wounded/Injured, Shot - Dead (murder, accidental, suicide), Suicide - Attempt, Murder/Suicide, Attempted Murder/Suicide (one variable unsuccessful), Institution/Group/Business, Mass Murder (4+ deceased victims excluding the subject/suspect/perpetrator , one location), Mass Shooting (4+ victims injured or killed excluding the subject/suspect)'
df = pd.DataFrame({'incident_characteristics': [txt]})
df['incident_characteristics'].str.extractall(r'([\w\+\-\/ ]+(\([\w\+\-\/\, ]+\))?)')[0]
```

Output:

```
#    match
# 0  0                                   Shot - Wounded/Injured
#    1                Shot - Dead (murder, accidental, suicide)
#    2                                        Suicide - Attempt
#    3                                           Murder/Suicide
#    4         Attempted Murder/Suicide (one variable unsucc...
#    5                               Institution/Group/Business
#    6         Mass Murder (4+ deceased victims excluding th...
#    7         Mass Shooting (4+ victims injured or killed e...
# Name: 0, dtype: object
```

If you use `.str.split`, the first letter will be removed as it is used as a part of delimiter.

```
df['incident_characteristics'].str.split(r',\s[A-Z]', expand=True)
```

Output:

```
#                         0                                         1  \
# 0  Shot - Wounded/Injured  hot - Dead (murder, accidental, suicide)
#                   2              3  \
# 0  uicide - Attempt  urder/Suicide
#                                                    4  \
# 0  ttempted Murder/Suicide (one variable unsucces...
#                            5  \
# 0  nstitution/Group/Business
#                                                    6  \
# 0  ass Murder (4+ deceased victims excluding the ...
#                                                    7
# 0  ass Shooting (4+ victims injured or killed exc...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first create the data and then feed it into a dataframe, like so

```
import pandas as pd, re

junk = """Shot - Wounded/Injured, Shot - Dead (murder, accidental, suicide), Suicide - Attempt, Murder/Suicide, Attempted Murder/Suicide (one variable unsuccessful), Institution/Group/Business, Mass Murder (4+ deceased victims excluding the subject/suspect/perpetrator , one location), Mass Shooting (4+ victims injured or killed excluding the subject/suspect"""

rx = re.compile(r'\([^()]+\)|,(\s+)')

data = [x 
        for nugget in rx.split(junk) if nugget
        for x in [nugget.strip()] if x]

df = pd.DataFrame({'incident_characteristics': data})
print(df)
```

This yields

```
                            incident_characteristics
0                             Shot - Wounded/Injured
1                                        Shot - Dead
2                                  Suicide - Attempt
3                                     Murder/Suicide
4                           Attempted Murder/Suicide
5                         Institution/Group/Business
6                                        Mass Murder
7  Mass Shooting (4+ victims injured or killed ex...
```

Additionally, this assumes that commas in parentheses should be ignored when splitting.