# regex in string pandas (split)

Tags: python, regex, split

Hello I have a strings such as :

```
liste_to_split=['NW_011625257.1_0','scaffold1_3','scaffold3']
```

and I would like to split them at the `Number_Number`
I tried :

```
for i in liste_to_split:
 i.split(r'(?<=[0-9])_')
```

and I got

```
['NW_011625257.1_0']
['scaffold1_3']
['scaffold3']
```

instead of

```
['NW_011625257.1'] ['0']
['scaffold1'] ['3']
['scaffold3']
```

does someone knows where is the issue ?

Comment: You are using `str.split` - use `re.split`

Comment: **A duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919003/pandas-split-on-regex?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209288/split-string-based-on-regex**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use:

```
>>> import re
>>> liste_to_split=['NW_011625257.1_0','scaffold1_3','scaffold3']
>>> 
>>> for i in liste_to_split:
...     re.split(r'(?<=[0-9])_', i)
...
['NW_011625257.1', '0']
['scaffold1', '3']
['scaffold3']
```

Note use of `re.split` instead of `string.split` and using `_` outside lookbehind assertion to make sure we are not splitting on a zero width match.

---

Based on OP's comment below it seems OP wants to do this splitting for a `dataframe` column. In that case use:

Assuming this is your dataframe:

```
>>> print (df)
             column
0  NW_011625257.1_0
1       scaffold1_3
2         scaffold3
```

Then you can use:

```
>>> print (df['column'].str.split(r'(?<=[0-9])_', expand=True))
                0     1
0  NW_011625257.1     0
1       scaffold1     3
2       scaffold3  None
```

Comment: and what if it is on dataframe ? I can still use re ? example ```df['column'].re.split(i.split(r'(?<=[0-9])_') ```

Comment: Since you haven't shown a dataframe that's answer is based on code provided in question. But yes dataframe also has a split but in different form. Please update your question so that I can help further.

Comment: You can use: `df['column'].str.split(r'(?<=[0-9])_')` or check updated answer.

Comment: Please reclose the question, it is still a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919003/pandas-split-on-regex?rq=1 and as written now, still a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209288/split-string-based-on-regex

Comment: I rarely reopen dupe questions but it was one of them due to mismatch between title and question body. I have already requested OP to edit the question. Once question is edited I will revisit to check dupe with this link.

Answer (score 1):

```
l=['NW_011625257.1_0','scaffold1_3','scaffold3']

for i in l:
  f = i.split('_')
  print(f)
```

output

```
['NW', '011625257.1', '0']
['scaffold1', '3']
['scaffold3']
```