# Split dataframe string based on words and store them in a dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dataframe

In my dataframe I have some Name and I want to split it based on some words.

Dataframe (dff):

```
 id            name
  1     Midian Almeida(Last)
  2     Robert(ASA)(first)
  3     Nikole John (middle)
  4     Nikole John (first)
  5     Raça Negra  (last)
```

I want to split them based one first,last,middle

I tried the below part

dff['name'].str.split('(first)|(last)|(middle)', expand=True).add_prefix('name_')
It gives the below output:

```
    name_0 
  Midian Almeida                
    Robert(ASA)       
    Nikole John       
    Nikole John      
    Raça Negra
```

but I want to put the split words in another column.
desired output is:

```
 id           name       split option
  1     Midian Almeida    (Last)
  2     Robert(ASA)       (first)
  3     Nikole John       (middle)
  4     Nikole John       (first)
  5     Raça Negra        (last)
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This contains what you need: [Pandas split on regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919003/pandas-split-on-regex).
The following should work:

```py
df.name.str.split(r'(\(Last\)|\(first\)|\(middle\))', expand=True)[[0, 1]]
```

The reason you need the regex is because you need the capture group, in this case the parentheses around the whole matching string. If you want to play around with regex to get a better feel for it, you can use the following: https://regex101.com/

Comment: THanks a lot! how can include the id here?

Comment: you can just reassign the columns, `name` should be `0` and `split option` should be `1`. Since the result is the same length the id will match up.