# Is there a Pandas equivalent to Excel's 'Text to Column', using the movable delimeter?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I would like to split some columns in my dataframe based off of certain keywords and integers.  In excel, this would look like this using the moveable delimiter:

[image].

I am aware of Pandas' `str.split` but this seems limited to one delimiter at a time, and does not seem to account for integers. With regex, I could do something like this to split the string accordingly

```
s = "zone entries bin 1 zone center"
s = re.split(r'(bin)|(\s+[0-9]+\s+)', s)
```

(I am not great at regex and with this latter result I'd have to remove `None` values). But it seems like regex expressions won't work with Pandas `str.split`. What is the most optimal way to accomplish this Text to Column functionality?

Comment: regex works with pandas str.split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.split` supports regular expressions. `Series.str.split(pat=None, n=- 1, expand=False)`

> `pat` : str, optional
> string or **regular expression** to split on. If not specified, split on whitespace.

See [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split). Also here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48921957/327165) with good examples.

Comment: Ok, it seems to work now. Maybe I wasn't using a regex expression properly when I was testing it out. However, the column values generates are not the same than splitting a string. In my example, the output would be `['zone entries ', 'bin', None, '', None, ' 10 ', 'zone center']`, but when applying `str.split` on the dataframe, the numbers end up in two columns mixed with `None`s.

Comment: @BrianBarry if you see an issue with regex behavior, please create reproducible example and post it as a new question.